# openCV RunningAvg implementation

Tags: opencv, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04

I am writing a small script (in Python) that generates and updates a running average of a camera feed. When I call cv.RunningAvg it returns:

```
cv2.error: func != 0
```

Where am I stumbling in implementing cv.RunningAvg? Script follows:

```
import cv

feed = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
frame = cv.QueryFrame(feed)
moving_average = cv.QueryFrame(feed)
cv.NamedWindow('live', cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

def loop():
    frame = cv.QueryFrame(feed)
    cv.ShowImage('live', frame)
    c = cv.WaitKey(10)

    cv.RunningAvg(frame, moving_average, 0.020, None)

while True:
    loop()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not sure about the error, but check out the documentation for **[cv.RunningAvg](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=running#accumulateweighted)**

It says **destination should be 32 or 64-bit floating point.**

So I made a small correction in your code and it works. I created a **32-bit floating point image to store running average values**, **then another 8 bit image so that I can show running average image :**

```
import cv2.cv as cv

feed = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
frame = cv.QueryFrame(feed)
moving_average = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame),32,3) # image to store running avg
avg_show = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame),8,3) # image to show running avg

def loop():
    frame = cv.QueryFrame(feed)
    c = cv.WaitKey(10)

    cv.RunningAvg(frame, moving_average, 0.1, None)
    cv.ConvertScaleAbs(moving_average,avg_show) # converting back to 8-bit to show

    cv.ShowImage('live', frame)
    cv.ShowImage('avg',avg_show)

while True:
    loop()

cv.DestroyAllWindows()
```

Now see the result :

At a particular instant, I saved a frame and its corresponding running average frame.

**Original frame :**

[image]

`You can see the obstacle (my hand) blocks the objects in behind`.

**Now running average frame** :

[image]

It almost removed my hand and shows objects in background.

That is how `it is a good tool for background subtraction`.

**One more example from a typical traffic video :**

[image]   [image]

You can see more details and samples here : http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/07/background-extraction-using-running.html